# Exit 'history' in fish

Tags: fish

I recently switched from bash to fish. I like it, but I don't know how to exit, when I enter `history`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `history` function will show your history in your pager program. This can changed by setting the `$PAGER` variable, but usually it's a program called `less`.

And to quit that one, press <kbd>q</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>h</kbd> will show you the help screen.

If it's not less or something similar (most pagers quit with <kbd>q</kbd>, to be honest), then it depends on that program.

Answer (score 1):

The `history` command in the `fish` shell displays your command line history.  It does this in a pager, possibly `less` or `more`.

To exit the pager, press <kbd>q</kbd>.